# PDF files do not display properly in browser

Tags: php, pdf

We are trying to display a `PDF File` from Live Server (PHP Verion 5.2) which is not getting displayed properly... instead of file `bytecode` is getting displayed..

Same file is getting displayed if we are trying to display from Local Server(PHP Version 5.4)..

We have tried following to display PDF from Server (Which displays ByteCode):

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($url_path));  // '$url_path' variable is fullpath to PDF file
readfile($url_path) or die("File not found ");
```

**Output ByteCode:**

```
%PDF-1.5 2 0 obj << >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 598 834] /Contents 4 0 R /Resources << /XObject << /img0 5 0 R >> /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageC] /Font 2 0 R >> /Annots 6 0 R >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 61 >> stream x
```

If we try to display using below line then it works fine..

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location.href = '".$url_path."'; </script>";
```

We already tried changing .htaccess code as below:

```
(1) RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+).pdf$  /cgi-bin/pdf.php?file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]


(2) RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /viewpdf.php?request_url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Still not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

While declaring `header` we should take care that no `echo` or `print_r` should be declared before it..

And if we import file in `require(..)` or `include(..)` or `require_once(..)` also should not contain any `echo` statement.. otherwise all `header` declaration after that will be ignored..

**In short:** ***above the header statement no echo statement should be written otherwise all header declaration will be ignored..***

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply print object bytecode of class in php and use header("Content-type: application/pdf") funtion to print pdf